# how to groupby on only one column using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, group-by

Thanks for looking

My data

```
Easting          Northing         Street        Town        postcode
123454           887878           main          yourTown    gh6 0jh
098345           093978           main          yourTown    gh6 0jh
872982           873839           main          yourTown    gh6 0jh
849728           938393           south         yourTown    gh6 8uh
748494           817263           south         yourTown    gh6 8uh
989893           787878           high          yourTown    gh6 7mu
889955           992002           high          yourTown    gh6 7mu
882999           998339           high          yourTown    gh6 7mu
```

My linq statement

```
return this._uow.Addresses
    .Where(a => a.Street.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(street.Trim().ToUpper()))
    .Select(a => 
        new Street() 
        { 
            MapEast = a.MapEast, 
            MapNorth = a.MapNorth, 
            Details = a.Street + " " + a.Town + " " + a.PostCode 
        })
    .AsEnumerable();
```

I am needing the only one occurrence of the  Street, Town, postcode and then eastings and northing to go with that one record. I am not concerned with which record that is selected. Is this done with a groupby? I have been messing around with this with groupby but cannot figure it out. hope you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then use a group by, and take for example the first item in the group

```
.GroupBy(m => new {m.Street, m.Town, m.PostCode)
.Select(g => g.First());//You will get first Address
```

or in your case

```
.Where(<yourWhereClause>)
.GroupBy(m => new {m.Street, m.Town, m.PostCode})
.Select(m => new Street {
       MapEast = m.FirstOrDefault().MapEast,//"random" MapEast
       MapNorth = m.FirstOrDefault().MapNorth,//"random" MapNorth
       Details = a.Key.Street + " " + a.Key.Town + " " + a.Key.PostCode
});
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. VS is telling me to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`. But seems to be working

Comment: @Easty oh yes, always forget this... Even if this is a FirstOrDefault which is never null...